# How to Check Internet Connection Continuously in Android | Java | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, webview, connection

I was working in android studio 421 for some days, I am very much new to android development. Here I need to check the internet connection, if internet is there I need to display a webpage, and if internet is not there, I need to display an alert box saying 'no internet connection found'. This is the code I have done so far.

```
package com.example.x;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(web.canGoBack())
            web.goBack();
    }


    WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        web.loadUrl(getString(R.string.u));
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    }






    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

But the alert is not showing when there is no internet connection.

I have enabled

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml. I am stucked here, I don't know what to do next. I googled alot, but couldn't find an answer. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You should almost never (including in this case) check for anything continuously. Rather, register for notifications when the state changes.

Comment: Exactly. The best way to check whether any resource is available is to try to use it in the normal way at the point you need it. Any other technique constitutes trying to foretell the future. You have to handle the error at the usage site anyway: why write any more code?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check the internet connection, if internet is there I need to display a webpage, and if internet is not there, I need to display an alert box saying 'no internet connection found'.

So, this some how contradicts with the question title (to continuously observe the internet connection)

So, in case you just need to check if the internet connection is available, you can check that with the system service `Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` by triggering `connectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo()` but since this is deprecated on API-21, you need to migrate that to `connectivityMgr.getAllNetworks()`

Integrating this into a utility method:

```
public boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    boolean isConnected = false;
    ConnectivityManager   mConnectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        // Checking internet connectivity
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
        if (mConnectivityMgr != null) {
            activeNetwork = mConnectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); // Deprecated in API 29
        }
        isConnected = activeNetwork != null;

    } else {
        Network[] allNetworks = mConnectivityMgr.getAllNetworks(); // added in API 21 (Lollipop)

        for (Network network : allNetworks) {
            NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = mConnectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
            if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET))
                    isConnected = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return isConnected;

}
```

Then you can do:

```
if (isOnline(MainActivity.this)) {
    // display a webpage
} else {
    // display an alert box saying 
}
```